# Function to find the dot product of two vectors and the angle between them (function that returns two values)

Tags: c, function, pointers

Trying to write a program that can calculate the dot product of and angle in degrees between two vectors. I need to use one function to do both of these. Is there a way to do this with pointers? The code I have right now gives -nan(ind) if I try the dot product and angle branch. This is my code (the program also finds the magnitude of one vector, but I'm focusing on the dot product and angle parts right now):

```c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double find_dotprod_andangled(v1, v2, v3, w1, w2, w3);
double find_magnitude(double v1, double v2, double v3);

int main(void) {
    
    double v1, v2, v3, w1, w2, w3, mag, dot;
    char a;

    printf("Enter M/m or magnitude or D/d for the dot product and angle in degrees: ");
    scanf("%c", &a);

    if (a == 'M' || a == 'm') {
        printf("Enter in values for v1, v2, and v3: ");
        scanf("%lf,%lf,%lf", &v1, &v2, &v3);
        printf("The magnitude of the vector is: %lf", find_magnitude(v1, v2, v3));
    }

    if (a == 'D' || a == 'd') {
        printf("Enter in vector 1: ");
        scanf("%lf,%lf,%lf", &v1, &v2, &v3);
        printf("Enter in vector 2: ");
        scanf("%lf,%lf,%lf", &w1, &w2, &w3);

        printf("The dot product of the vectors is: %lf", find_dotprod_andangled(v1, v2, v3, w1, w2, w3));
    }

    return(0);
}

double find_magnitude(double v1, double v2, double v3) {
    double mag;
    mag = sqrt(pow(v1, 2) + pow(v2, 2) + pow(v3, 2));
    return(mag);
}

double find_dotprod_andangled(double v1, double v2, double v3, double w1, double w2, double w3) {
    double dot, mag1, mag2, theta;
    double pi = 3.14159265359;
    mag1 = sqrt(pow(v1, 2) + pow(v2, 2) + pow(v3, 2));
    mag2 = sqrt(pow(w1, 2) + pow(w2, 2) + pow(w3, 2));

    dot = (v1 * w1) + (v2 * w2) + (v3 * w3);
    theta = acos((dot / (mag1 * mag2)) * (180 / pi));
    return(dot,theta);
}
```

Comment: Return a struct.

Comment: `return(dot,theta);` What do you think that statement does?

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Inside your question, describe not only the problem you're having, and the expected and actual results, but also please ask your question inside the question itself and keep the title a short summary of your problem or question.

Comment: "I need to use one function to do both of these." That just sounds like poor design. On top of the potential poor design of passing a vector as three separate doubles. And the fact that `find_dotprod_andangled` does not use `find_magnitude`.